# PowerQuery - Custom Function, Loop that passes value throgh rows

Tags: function, loops, powerquery

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the value through the rows using custom function.
The background of the issue is that i have initial value, which is my warehouse stock of the product, i have some forecast of the sales in week perioids and i need to calculate if i need to place new delivery order or its ok and Stock is still above MinStock and no delivery needed in this week.
Ofc i need to place orders in specific quantity.

So the initial value in the first week is today Stock, but for the next week / next row (lets say 2nd) i need it to be [Stock from week 1] - SalesForecast + QtyToOrder

***Below a sample how my table actually looks***
[image]

Comment: How are you determining quantity to order?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're looking for is [running totals in dax](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/computing-running-totals-in-dax/) It makes more sense to do in dax so you're more flexible, by not pre-aggregating everything.